# How to prevent repeated text field input within the same Form.

Tags: php, javascript

I am creating a e-commerce website. In my website people can register and share their recipe. And in that recipe Form i have multiple text fields. Such as Recipe name, Ingredients, cooking time, cooking tools etc.Now anyone can just change the recipe name and send the same content over and over again to flood the database.My question is now: How can i prevent repeated text filed input within the same Form?"

Comment: please post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could use an MVC framework like Rails, that gives you several options including validations.

Second, you could implement a hash, that checks your needed conditions which you could insert as a hidden field in your form.

You can then check the hash after submitting the form. And if only the recipe name changed, than your hash would be the same as in the form.